# Passing multiple params with POST page to page with PHP

Tags: php

I have page1.php, with some params defined, and fetched from form with POST which I want to pass to another page, page2.php for example:

```
// File page1.php
$params = $_POST['params']; // nested array with form values

<form action="page2.php" method="POST">
<button type="submit" name="params[details]" value="some_value"></button>
</form> 

// File page2.php

$params = $_POST['params'];

print_r($params);

// I am only get params[details] value, not all passed values to page1.php
```

How can I pass all variables form page1.php to page2.php, not only submitted param from $params['details']?
Should I use $_SESSION variable instead? Is it secure enough, and are there any caveats?

Comment: $_SESSION data is only saved on the server, it's not sent to the client- so that's plenty secure (obviously depending on what data you're getting from the user). As they progress through your pages, just continue to save the form data to the session, and then process all the data from the session at the end.

Comment: Add all form input inside your `form` .

Comment: @Core972, I cant bloat form with only one input type

Comment: @MikelBitson Thats what I think too. I will save that in SEESSION

Comment: So fetch all fetched params to a $_SESSION. Don't forget you can use multiple session by naming them like this `$_SESSION[session_name][param1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't trust data sent to the user to resubmit to the next step. Use a session (or other persistent server side data storage) to hold the data.

All user input should be treated as potentially malicious.